# Connecting to MariaDB/HeidiSQL instance using AWS RDS - Python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, heidisql

I can't seem to find the key to bring it all together for me.

So I have an AWS RDS instance of a MariaDB database active. Then, upon downloading MariaDB, it actually downloaded HeidiSQL and a MySQL/MariaDB terminal to my Windows PC.

I was able to connect the HeidiSQL client to my AWS RDS using the endpoint and port number, and I created some databases.

Good.

Now, I am learning Python, so I installed Sypder (Anaconda3) on my computer. Can someone please explain to me how do I go about connecting my python file to my HeidiSQL/MariaDB/AWS RDS to see the databases I have created? I am trying to save the tables into a pandas dataframe on my .py.

I tried using the terminal on Spyder but it does not seem to recognize command 'mysql'. Does HeidiSQL have its own command?

Any help on how to go about it would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could used another python package such as pymsql to establish the connection to any Mysql instance including a RDS. please check this link https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).